# Shortest distance of point on circle and tangent line

Tags: geometry, circles

> $X$ is $2$ feet away from $CD$. The circle is tangent to $CD$ and $DE$. What is the shortest distance between $X$ and the line $DE$?

[image: et]

I proposed this question to a friend. My friend claimed that the answer was $25$ and $49$ because you could make another point that was also $2$ feet away from CD on the circle like so:

[image]

I suggested that the answer was only $25$ because I specified only $1$ point labeled X.

Does anyone know which answer is correct?

I don't really think that you should be able to create another point when there is one already labeled and specified.

Comment: "I forgot to mention...": did you forget to mention to your friend, or to us ?

Comment: I said this to my friend

Comment: Then there is a single solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you asked for the shortest distance, then $25$ should be the answer. Maybe you could also add something in the question like

> The point $X$ lies below the center of the circle.

which could make things crystal clear, but since you've specified that it is the **shortest distance**, it isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-r)^2+(y-r)^2 = r^2$$

$$  x^2+y^2-2 x r -2 y r+r^2=0$$

Plug in $x=2, r=37, $and we get *the quadratic equation*
$$ y^2-74 y +1225 =0 $$

after factoring has *two roots* for $y$

$$ (y-25)(y-49)=0$$

$$ (y=25),(y=49)$$

so your friend is more right.

Comment: You would get two points but I only labelled one x, so shouldn't there be only one answer?

Comment: The full solution consists of two points, one above the radius and the other below. Whether or not labelled both are equally correct and have the same distance from y-axis =2.